# How to find the numer of words in a string

Tags: java

I am try to find the number of words in a string by the next regex
"[\s+!,?._'@]" but for some reason when i am using the split method still its counting me the white space as a word and i don't understand why.

for the following input:

```
He is a very very good boy, isn't he?
```

i get:

```
11
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy

isn
t
he
```

and the desired output:

```
10
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy
isn
t
he
```

this is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    public class Solution {


        public static void main(String[] args) 
        { 
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          String s=scan.nextLine();
            int count = 0;
          String [] tokens = s.split("[\\s+!,?._'@]");
            System.out.println(tokens.length);
            for(int i = 0; i<tokens.length;i++){
                 System.out.println(tokens[i]);
        }
       }

   }
```

Comment: check for empty string and dont count that ?

Comment: Use Pattern / Matcher with word boundaries

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `s.split(" ").length`?

Comment: yes but i already insert to the regex the white space but for some reason the split method ignoring it. i know i can pass on the array and check if its empty but this is not effective.

Comment: I think it might be a problem with the "," before the underline. You only check for one character in your s.split?

Comment: Mike but still its inserting into tokens white space string as you can see in the output.

Comment: Is it really desired that `isn` and `t` are considered separate words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `"He is a very very good boy, isn't he?"` contains a `", "`; your regex will treat this as 2 separate matches, one for `','` and one for `' '`. Simply add a `+` to the end of your regex:

```
String [] tokens = s.split("[\\s+!,?._'@]+");
```

Tested on [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/) and got 11 matches without the extra `+` and 10 with.

Comment: Although isn't is one word, not two. :)

Comment: very true, although it is short for 'is not' which might be what OP is after since the 't' is explicitly in the desired output, but I might be wrong :P

Answer (score 4):

Your regular expression only counts a comma as one delimiter, not "a comma and whitespace following it".  Also, your only `+` "one or more" metacharacter inside the brackets isn't applied; it's interpreted literally within brackets.

Move the `+` outside the bracket, so that anything inside the brackets can count one or more times as the delimiter.

```
String[] tokens = s.split("[\\s!,?._'@]+");
```

This will count `", "` as one delimiter so the output won't show a blank line between "boy" and "isn".

Comment: Isn't the `+` a literal even inside the brackets?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pattern` and `Matcher` with word-boundary like this. I suggest steering clear from the *splitting* approach as it could cause problems in case you don't know which delimiters are present in your string. :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[a-zA-Z]+\\b");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    int count = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

O/P :

```
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy
isn
t
he
10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Regex`, use a `Pattern` and `Matcher` combination.

```
    String s = "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?";
    String pattern = "(\\w+'?\\w*)";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(s);

    int wordCount = 0;
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println("Found word: " + m.group());
        wordCount++;
    }
    System.out.println("Word count: " + wordCount);
```

Gives me the output:

```
Found word: He
Found word: is
Found word: a
Found word: very
Found word: very
Found word: good
Found word: boy
Found word: isn't
Found word: he
Word count: 9
```

The regex pattern I used is:

```
(\\w+'?\\w*)
```

The `\\w+` matches 1 or more of any alphanumeric character, the `'?` matches 0 or 1 ' character (for words like isn't, doesn't, etc), and the extra `\\w*` accounts for 0 or more alphanumeric characters after the ' character. There might be better regex to use, but that was working for me.